# What can we do for the error "No error field found in JSON" (VDM:401)?

Tags: s4sdk

We try to call the API `API_BUSINESS_PARTNER` via our Java application. The Java implementation communicates with a SAPUI5 - Front End application, so that the data can be displayed via an app. 
Through our On - Premise System it works without any problems and we also get back data. But via the application we get the error "No error field found in JSON" and the SCP - Log for ODataConnectivityUtil shows us that the respective user is not authorized. 
Accordingly we tried to call an older one `MMIM_MATERIAL_DATA_SRV` and it works without any problems. We get the same error message in `API_PRODUCT_SRV`. So it doesn't seem to work with the new APIs in general.

Thank you,
best regards.

- [The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5kK2.png)
- [Our source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wazws.png)
- [Logging snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UOXd.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks again for the support.

We have solved the problem now. 
The problem is that the first metadata request is executed on the default client (client 100) although we have set "sap-client=200" in the destination configuration. 
Our passwords between the clients were different, so we received an authentication error.

We suspect that the "newer" API's will not be able to access the configuration for the destination from the SCP. So it probably worked with the older ones.

One problem for us was that the Cloud SDK does not take the client from the destination configuration (for the metadata request).

The other problem was that the error message "No error field found in JSON" was misleading.

Only by the tip with "ODataConnectivityUtil", we could see our authentication error. So thanks again.

Comment: With version 2.0.0 of the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK, the SAP Client is handled automatically and sent as a header to the destination system. See https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/6c02295dfa8f47cf9c08a19f2e172901/1.0/en-US/index.html#version-2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the S/4HANA Cloud SDK are you using? This might be an issue that we had in an older version. Could you update to the latest release version and give it a try again?

Details on releases can be found here:
https://sap.github.io/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/release-notes/

**Hint:** I would also suggest to use our virtual data model classes that we provide for invoking such OData services. You can find a blog post on this topic here: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/21/step-4-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-calling-an-odata-service/

Comment: We use the version 1.6.0

Comment: Could you try with the data model classes, in your case, this should be the BusinessPartnerService which is also part of the blog post mentioned above.

Comment: With this one I get the error message: "The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 401. Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen. 401 nicht autorisiert". This was the reason why we use the ODataQueryBuilder().

Comment: Have you been able to exclude failing authentication as cause for this error? 
Normally when one of your queries produces an error, the server will respond with a JSON explaining the error. However, if you fail to authenticate, the server responds with an HTML document.
The error handler used by the query builder expects the error to be a JSON and therefore tries to access the JSONs "error" field. Since the document is HTML though, this fails. The VDM error handler correctly parses the HTML and shows you the 401 message. So I'm guessing your authentication actually fails in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot completely rule that out. The On - Premise system provides us data for client 200 without any problems. In SCP, our ErpQueryEndpoint is configured accordingly.  So if we had authorization problems, we shouldn't get the data from the On Premise system, should we?

Comment: I guess you are using Basic Authentication? Could you check the log output for error messages following the request to your endpoint and post this here? Thanks!

Comment: Here you will find our log file:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApnV2niElr6SiQjLFIzsTOFbVmUL

Thank you

Comment: From the log, this looks like an authentication issue on S/4HANA side (indicated by the HTML inside the message). Can you please try another user to rule out a potential authentication issue with the user?

Comment: Hello @N.Kryl, is your problem solved with those hints? If so, It would be nice if you accepted one of the answers. Otherwise, please provide more details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pls take a look in the S/4HANA OData log which you can find using transaction /iwfnd/error_log (put /n before it). 
Then you execute the OData call to provoke the error. If you then find an entry in the OData log, it does mean that the authentication to S/4HANA was succesful. Also then you would figure out mor error details.
In case you do not find any entry, it is very likely that you are not authenticating correctly. In this case S/4HANA returns 401 and an HTML document as response payload.

Comment: As suspected, nothing is entered in the ERROR_LOG. We generally also call some BAPI's from the On - Premise system via RFC. Here it works without any problems. But as mentioned above, we also call an older API "MMIM_MATERIAL_DATA_SRV" via HTTP and it works without problems. Only the "newer" API's have problems with this. Is it necessary to accept configurations for the new API's in the On - Premise system?